# how to create tabs with arches between them?

Tags: css, tabs, navigation

below is an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Can I make this with pure CSS?

UPDATE: I've created divs with rounded corners (using border-radius) on the upper right and left corners and placing them between the tabs. Still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can give corners a border radius with css but you'll most likely need to use some images to get the effect above. http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: If you want a proper solution, please show what you've tried so people don't waste their time trying the same thing or telling you what you already know.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to overlay an element over the menu items, that has a border-radius itself. This element has to have the same background color as the container of the menu.

Those overlays should be done with the pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`. Those also have a great [browser support](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/).

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patv</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear:both;" /> <!-- I didn't have an other element to clear the floats with -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs { /* generates the grey line on the very top */
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: grey;
}

.tabs li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

.tabs li:first-child {
    margin-left: 30px; /* This is just to move the menu to the left, for demo purposes */
}

.tabs a {
    text-underline: none;
    color: black;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background: grey;
}

.tabs a:after, .tabs li:first-child a:before {
    content: '';
    width: 4px;
    height: 25px;
    background: white; /* This has to be the background color of the container. Change it to red to see the pseudo elements */ 
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.tabs a:after {
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rGubz/

Comment: the first white `:after` element is in the 'archive' tab instead of being outside.

Comment: @user701510 Can you make a screenshot? I'm not sure what you mean. (And what browser?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `border-radius` property. But, `border-radius` is a CSS3 property.

Comment: Notice that in between the links, they flange outwards. Care to explain how this is done with `border-radius`?

Comment: @Madmartigan, you just have to place a dummy div between all the links, and style it's top corner with border-radius; for links div style the bottom corners with border-radius

Comment: You should direct your advice towards user701510, and edit the solution into your post instead of the comments.

Comment: hey sorry for mentioning this, but I've tried your solution of placing dummy divs before posting the question. Updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use negative border radiuses

http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

It may not be compliant in all browsers, your safest using images for the outward radius

Updating my answer to use pure CSS without negative radius
http://jsfiddle.net/peter/QTS6N/1/

Comment: I'm not sure how a negative border radius would help since it's going inwards?

Comment: With two divs, the first layer could have a top border for the orange. Another div overlayed holding the ul and li elements. Every other li element could have a negative border in between the tabs with a padding or margin set and you may be able to get the effect with pure CSS but graphics would be a safe way.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle showing one method using pure CSS http://jsfiddle.net/peter/QTS6N/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using 'negative border radius', basically radial gradients (may not be cross-browser compatible tho, may be worth it to just use graphics).  Take a look at [this article](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/).  Good luck!

Comment: Just noticed @Anagio beat me to the punch on that one!

Comment: I'm not sure how a negative border radius would help since it's going inwards?

Comment: From what I understand it's not really a negative border radius, it is a radial gradient that is made to look like you are using a negative border radius.  Honestly, if it were me, I'd use graphics if this is something that is a must-have, because the radial gradient effect is not a feature that is completely supported (Internet Exploder, cough cough) yet, and from what I read in the article, takees a lot of css to make it look the way you want in the browsers that do support it.

Comment: FWIW, If you are looking future-forward you might try a combination of the radial gradient 'negative border radius' effect with a stylesheet that uses a graphic for browsers that don't support this feature yet.